# want to design bootstrap horizontal form with addons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to design horizontal form with Bootstrap

1. want to add addons on left side of input field.
2. responsive but labels stay stable.
3. some fields on 2 coloumns.

[image: example]

```
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
  <fieldset class="col-xs-6">
    <legend>Portfolio A</legend>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Label A1</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="control1" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-xs-4 control-label">label A2</label>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="control2" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     </fieldset>
   <fieldset class="col-xs-6">
    <legend>Portfolio B</legend>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Label B1</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="control1" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label for="name" class="col-xs-4 control-label">label B2</label>
         <div class="col-xs-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control"    placeholder="control2" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can add the addons by using ::after selector. an interesting tutorial about custom select boxes with the :fter selector: http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/custom-select-drop-downs-with-css3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Docs: you can use text, font icons etc. [Bootstrap 3 Input groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups)

```css
#soForm .form-control {
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
#soForm .input-group-addon {
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 13px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #soForm .soForm {
    margin: 10px auto;
  }
  #soForm .control-label {
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <form id="soForm" name="soForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Label 1</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control soForm" id="text1" placeholder="Text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Label 2</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="input-group soForm"> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span></span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text2" placeholder="Text" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Label 3</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="input-group soForm"> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text3" placeholder="Text" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text4" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Label 4</label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="input-group soForm"> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span></span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text4" placeholder="Text" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text5" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Label 5</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control soForm" id="text5" placeholder="Text" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: thnk u 4 answer. but how abt point 3. 2 fields in 2 column. also labels stay stable

Comment: You'll generally have issues with horizontal forms once the viewport is reduced. It's all dependent on the structure of your actual form: if you don't need much width for your inputs you might be okay to reduce it all the way down. I personally consider what the user has to experience and therefore it can just make sense to stack everything once your down to a mobile viewport. I edited my answer with some options.

Comment: is that possible that u can make it like image i have uplaoded. because i can either in-line or horizontal design. i know its not hard. but for me it is.

Comment: Check the update and please remember to check your question as answered so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score -1):

```css
#soForm .form-control {
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
#soForm .input-group-addon {
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 13px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #soForm .soForm {
    margin: 10px auto;
  }
  #soForm .control-label {
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <form id="soForm" name="soForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Label 1</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control soForm" id="text1" placeholder="Text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Label 2</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="input-group soForm"> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span></span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text2" placeholder="Text" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Label 3</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="input-group soForm"> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text3" placeholder="Text" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text4" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Label 4</label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="input-group soForm"> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span></span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text4" placeholder="Text" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text5" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Label 5</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control soForm" id="text5" placeholder="Text" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```